# How to hide logs generated by play framework

Tags: playframework, logback, slf4j

```xml
<configuration>
    <conversionRule conversionWord="coloredLevel" converterClass="play.api.Logger$ColoredLevel" />
    <!--Appenders-->

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>/home/sankalp/logs/application.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <!-- set immediateFlush to false for much higher logging throughput -->
        <immediateFlush>false</immediateFlush>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>application1-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <!-- each file should be at most 5MB, keep 7 days worth of history, but at most 30MB -->
            <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>7</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>30MB</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <!-- encoders are assigned the type
             ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date - [%level] - from %logger in %thread %n%message%n%xException%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>



    <!--
      The logger name is typically the Java/Scala package name.
      This configures the log level to log at for a package and its children packages.
    -->
    <!--Loggers-->
    <logger name="com.exampleenter code here" level="INFO" />
 <!--   <logger name="application" level="DEBUG" />-->

    <!-- Off these ones as they are annoying, and anyway we manage configuration ourself -->
    <logger name="com.avaje.ebean.config.PropertyMapLoader" level="OFF" />
    <logger name="com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.XmlConfigLoader" level="OFF" />
    <logger name="com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.lib.BackgroundThread" level="OFF" />
    <logger name="com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript" level="OFF" />

    <!--Root logger-->
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

application.log file

```
2020-07-09 12:47:59,353 - [INFO] - from play in play-internal-execution-context-1 
datasource [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/ortholive_test_1may] bound to JNDI as DefaultDS

2020-07-09 12:47:59,361 - [WARN] - from com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPConfig in play-internal-execution-context-1 
LogStatementsEnabled is set to true, but log4j level is not set at DEBUG. Disabling statement logging.

2020-07-09 12:48:00,347 - [INFO] - from play in play-internal-execution-context-1 
database [default] connected at jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/ortholive_test_1may

2020-07-09 12:48:06,872 - [INFO] - from application in play-internal-execution-context-1 
Application redeployed : build V1

2020-07-09 12:48:07,032 - [INFO] - from play in play-internal-execution-context-1 
Starting application default Akka system.

2020-07-09 12:48:07,043 - [INFO] - from play in play-internal-execution-context-1 
Application started (Dev)

2020-07-09 12:48:07,114 - [INFO] - from akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger in play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5 
Slf4jLogger started

2020-07-09 12:48:10,439 - [WARN] - from com.jolbox.bonecp in play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5 
Query execute time limit exceeded (1587700ms) - query: select userpracti0_.id as id1_47_, userpracti0_.created_on as created_2_47_, userpracti0_.modified_on as modified3_47_, userpracti0_.practice_id as practice4_47_, userpracti0_.user_id as user_id5_47_ from ol_user_practice userpracti0_ cross join ol_practices practices1_ cross join ol_user user2_ where userpracti0_.practice_id=practices1_.id and userpracti0_.user_id=user2_.id and practices1_.practice_id='demo' and user2_.role_id=2

2020-07-09 12:48:10,443 - [WARN] - from com.jolbox.bonecp in play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2 
Query execute time limit exceeded (1608586ms) - query: select userpracti0_.id as id1_47_, userpracti0_.created_on as created_2_47_, userpracti0_.modified_on as modified3_47_, userpracti0_.practice_id as practice4_47_, userpracti0_.user_id as user_id5_47_ from ol_user_practice userpracti0_ cross join ol_user user1_ where userpracti0_.user_id=user1_.id and userpracti0_.practice_id=55 and user1_.role_id=3 order by userpracti0_.created_on desc

2020-07-09 12:49:07,082 - [INFO] - from application in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2 

2020-07-09 12:49:07,082 - [INFO] - from application in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2 
started : Thu Jul 09 12:49:07 IST 2020

2020-07-09 12:49:07,083 - [INFO] - from application in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2 

2020-07-09 12:49:07,671 - [INFO] - from application in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2 

2020-07-09 12:49:07,671 - [INFO] - from application in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2 
Ended : Thu Jul 09 12:49:07 IST 2020

2020-07-09 12:49:07,671 - [INFO] - from application in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2 

2020-07-09 13:00:00,058 - [INFO] - from application in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2 
Ruuning scheduleForCST7AMThu Jul 09 13:00:00 IST 2020

2020-07-09 13:04:07,071 - [INFO] - from application in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2 

2020-07-09 13:04:07,072 - [INFO] - from application in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2 
started : Thu Jul 09 13:04:07 IST 2020

2020-07-09 13:04:07,073 - [INFO] - from application in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2 

2020-07-09 13:04:07,086 - [INFO] - from application in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2 

2020-07-09 13:04:07,087 - [INFO] - from application in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2 
Ended : Thu Jul 09 13:04:07 IST 2020

2020-07-09 13:04:07,087 - [INFO] - from application in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2 

2020-07-09 13:19:07,092 - [INFO] - from application in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2 

2020-07-09 13:19:07,092 - [INFO] - from application in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2 
started : Thu Jul 09 13:19:07 IST 2020

2020-07-09 13:19:07,092 - [INFO] - from application in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2 
----------------------------------------------------------

2020-07-09 13:19:07,100 - [INFO] - from application in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2 

2020-07-09 13:19:07,101 - [INFO] - from application in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2 
Ended : Thu Jul 09 13:19:07 IST 2020

2020-07-09 13:19:07,103 - [INFO] - from application in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specified `<root level="INFO">` and this sets default logging level for ALL loggers to be `INFO` thus you see `INFO` log events from `akka`, `play`, `com.jolbox` etc.

You should set root to a less chatty log level. It's usually set to `WARN` or `ERROR`.

```xml
    <root level="WARN">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
```

Make sure that logger for your application is enabled.

```xml
<logger name="package.to.your.classes" level="INFO" />
```

Comment: Thank you.Is there any way it print only my logs and avoid all other logs because Now it's avoiding some logs but still below logs coming --
`2020-07-09 16:03:17,088 - [INFO] - from application in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4 
----------------------------------------------------------

2020-07-09 16:03:17,089 - [INFO] - from application in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4 
started : Thu Jul 09 16:03:17 IST 2020

2020-07-09 16:03:17,090 - [INFO] - from application in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4 
-------------------------------------------------`

Comment: @SandeepSingh What are "my" logs, the logs produced with logger `application`?

Comment: @SandeepSingh how do you define it? Add the code sample please

Comment: Now its working fine I just remove `<logger name="application" level="INFO" />`
below is sample code
`class A{

 private static final org.slf4j.Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(A.class);
 
 public void test(){
  
  logger.info("This is test method");
 
 }

}
`